# Flutter hot restart take long time after updating to Flutter 1.20

Tags: flutter

After I updated Flutter to 1.20.0, now it takes a long time to accomplish.
The last one takes 208,703ms.
I tried updating to Flutter 1.20.1 but there is no difference.

**Is there anyone knows how to solve it?**

**Thank you!**

Comment: This question should be on Flutter Github and not here.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I also got an error saying "character.dart is missing", it didnt even let me simulate on the emulator, so I downgraded it back to 1.17.5. I used the cmd command flutter downgrade :)